# Connecting to a base class' signal when overriding it in a subclass

Tags: c++, qt

Qt provides the `QSpinBox`, which is some far `QObject` derivative that provides a signal:

```
class QSpinBox:
    public /* ... */ QObject {

    signals:
        void valueChanged(int i);
};
```

When deriving from this spin box, I might provide an override for this signal to emit some beautified version of the value:

```
class MySpinBox:
    public QSpinBox {

    private slots:
        void originalValueChanged(int i) {
            /* Beautify */
            emit valueChanged( 42 * i );
        }

    signals:
        void valueChanged(int myPersonalI);
};
```

This seems perfectly fine: The signal `MySpinBox::valueChanged(int)` hides the inherited signal. The only bit missing is to connect the inherited `QSpinBox::valueChanged(int)` to the private slot `MySpinBox::originalValueChanged(int)`.

While this is possible using the *new* signals and slot syntax:

```
connect(
    static_cast<QSpinBox *>(this), &QSpinBox::valueChanged,
    this, &MySpinBox::originalValueChanged);
```

I am neither sure if this is *allowed* or *sensible*, nor how to connect the signal using the conventional string based signal/slot syntax. Using the latter, the slot is obviously connected to the `MySpinBox::originalValueChanged(int)` signal, which is clearly not intended.

### Purpose

The above example is reduced to the problem I think I face. To understand why I ran into the problem and maybe to guide me out of this (pretended) broken design, think of a `QDoubleSpinBox` derivative to enter some physical quantitiy, e.g. speed. The user may want to enter this in some preferred unit, which may be `km/h` or `mph`. To get the unit conversion logic out of the application, I composed a new widget, derived from `QWidget` and containing only a `QDoubleSpinBox`. Then I implemented the usual spin box methods (`setMinimum`, `setSingleStep` etc.) that take the respective properties in SI dimension (i.e., `m/s` in this example), convert them to some chosen unit and then configure the inferior double spin box.

A `setValue(double)` converts its argument to the user's unit and passes it on to the inferior. In turn, there is a `valueChanged(double)` signal that is emitted whenever the inferior spin box emits `valueChanged`, but with the quantity converted back to the SI dimension.

So in the end I was tinkering about not composing a `QWidget` derivative with an inferior spin box but to derive from the `QDoubleSpinBox` and reimplement.

Pros and cons appear *partly* clear, including the issue explained by @Pavel Strakhov below already. Composing the widget in fact gets me rid of *wrongly inherited* methods being called (due to not being virtual), at the cost of a wrapping `QWidget`. So as an intermediate step, I'm tinkering of deriving *private* from `QDoubleSpinBox`. This is surely not a matter of resources in a GUI application, but to me it's also a matter of learning and tinkering.

Then I stumbled about the signal and wondered what Qt might think about it.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not so reasonable, but before jumping into low-level detail corrections, I am interested in what exactly you are trying to achieve with "beautfying". It would be easier to help if you mentioned your use case. It is possible at this point that even the beautifying is incorrect and this can be addressed better at a higher layer of the design stage. So, please elaborate.

Comment: Added a clarification. Hoping not to fail as badly as last time. Please feel free to request further information at the slightest doubt, before investing too much time :-}

Answer (score 0):

Note that `QSpinBox::valueChanged` is not virtual, meaning that if one have an instance of `MySpinBox` stored in `QSpinBox*` pointer and calls its `valueChanged` method, `QSpinBox::valueChanged` will be executed instead of `MySpinBox::valueChanged`. And Qt internal functions will definitely have `QSpinBox*` pointer to the instance. This inconsistency can be a source of errors. Non-virtual functions are not meant to be redefined in subclasses, and you should not do that. Neither of Qt built-in classes uses such redefinition. Subclasses usually add new signals leaving base class signals untouched.